# How do I only change first letter into a capital using ascii in python

Tags: python, ascii, capitalization

The code I currently have makes it so that the entire word is capitalised instead of just the first letter which is what I am trying to accomplish.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FgE7.png

Comment: Look into the `.title()` method for strings

Comment: [`str.title`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) read the tutorial and documentation...

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
.[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice method for `str` called `.capitalize()`

```py
word = "hello"
word.capitalize()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word = "pinklemon1998"

_word = word[0].upper() + word[1:]
```

Or as mentioned in the comments:

```
_word = word.title()
```